# regular expression does not return expected result

Tags: python

i want to return a digit string, but the regular expression output is not as expected.

i use regular expression, i think the `[\.\d+]*` should match . with some digits, but output seems wrong.

```
t1 = re.findall(r'[\-|\+]?\d+[\.\d+]*', a)
```

i tried some fix on this pattern, but all not expected

input： 1234567890abcdef-123456.789.45879.237489237492..323.ae

the result:

```
['1234567890', '-123456.789', '789.45879', '45879.237489237492', '237489237492.', '.323', '323.']
```

but i think the `'237489237492.', '.323', '323.'` is not necessary, what happened???

Comment: what is your input

Comment: Go here to experiment with your regular expression: https://regex101.com/

Comment: input：1234567890abcdef-123456.789.45879.237489237492..323.ae

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general approach for matching positive/negative floating point numbers with optional decimal components, then use:

```
t1 = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b', a)
```

### Demo

Comment: I think it's not quite this easy. A valid result might also have a decimal point without any digits in front of it; and if I'm thinking clearly, changing the first + to a * leaves something that can match an empty string. The trick in the duplicate I found is to use `?` for the decimal point but `+` for the digit string after it and `*` before; when there is no decimal point but some number of digits, the `*` will capture all the digits; when there is a decimal point, `+` captures the digits thereafter; when there are no digits, the `+` fails whether there is a decimal point or not.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't consider `.123` to be a well-formed number, so I didn't bother taking that into account.

Answer (score 0):

> what happened???

Well,

> i think the `[\.\d+]*` should match . with some digits

"a period followed by one or more digits" is just `\.\d+`. But inside square brackets, like `[\.\d+]`, it becomes a character class: "a period, a digit or a plus sign" (and escaping the period doesn't matter):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[\.\d+]', 'foo.bar+baz89')
['.', '+', '8', '9']
```

...and then the `*` after that means to search for one of those characters *zero* or more times.

(Similarly, `[\-|\+]?` will also match a `|` symbol. All you want for that part is `[+-]?`. Perhaps you are thinking of grouping and alternation with the | symbol, but such grouping is done with `()`, not `[]`.)